# Android : After enabling ProGuard google cloud messaging (GCM) is not working

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, proguard

I am working on an app that runs properly while ProGuard was being disabled. Then I try to shrink my apk size and found [**ProGuard** as a recommended tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code).

When I enabled ProGuard, I got total **1153** warnings. Then have added `proguard-rules.txt` for customization. I just added the code snippet given in [ProGuard Manual Example for Android Application](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/examples#androidapplication). And added `-ignorewarnings` at the end of the `proguard-rules.text` file. Then, it compiled, build an signed apk and the apk ran smoothly.

But there is one problem ( there might be some other undiscovered problems too). That is the apk can not set GCM ID, a service is sending a single request continuously to the server, no GCM notification is received. But all these problems are solved in debug apk as there is no ProGuard enabled for debug apks.

Here is my `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ett"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 31
        versionName "1.0.18"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
    }

    lintOptions {
        // set to true to turn off analysis progress reporting by lint
        quiet true
        // if true, stop the gradle build if errors are found
        abortOnError false
        // if true, only report errors
        ignoreWarnings true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/MultipartUtility.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.mail.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/FCJsonParser.jar')
    compile files('libs/JSON.jar')
    compile files('libs/FCJsonChatParser.jar')
    compile files('libs/revmob.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-net-3.6.jar')

    compile project(':viewPagerIndicator')
    compile project(':connectionclass')
    compile project(':emojicons')

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'net.glxn.qrgen:android:2.0'
    compile 'org.apmem.tools:layouts:1.10@aar'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.8.4'
    compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.bartoszlipinski.recyclerviewheader:library:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.danielnilsson9:color-picker-view:1.4.0@aar'

    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-js-rhino:1.3.1'

    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.0'

    compile 'com.github.orangegangsters:swipy:1.2.3@aar'

    compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
}
```

and here is my `proguard-rules.txt`:

```
#-injars      bin/classes
-injars      libs
#-outjars     bin/classes-processed.jar
#-libraryjars /home/adnan/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar

-android
-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
      public <init>(android.content.Context);
      public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
      public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
      public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
    public void *(android.view.View);
    public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}

-dontwarn android.support.**
-ignorewarnings
```

How to solve this issue? Is there anything I didn't mention in `proguard-rules.txt` file? Thanks in advance. I have used `ProGuard version 6.0.3`

Comment: This suggestion will not solve your issue, but you might want to invest in changing to Firebase Cloud Messaging. As of April, 2018 GCM is depreciated and the server could be shut down April, 2019.

Comment: I second @Barns comment. GCM has been officially deprecated and it's been more than a year since it was advised to start migrating to FCM. FCM contains fixes to most of the issues that GCM had. Continuing to use GCM does not guarantee a smooth behavior/implementation compared to using FCM.